# Using ehcache3 with Spring4

Tags: spring, ehcache

Can someone please help with creating an Ehcache backed `CacheManager` using Spring `JCacheCacheManager` via xml? I have something like this. Not sure how to create a `javax.cache.CacheManager` for Ehcache3.

```
<bean id="myCacheManager"
    class="org.springframework.cache.jcache.JCacheCacheManager">
    <property name="cacheManager" value="..." />
</bean>
```

thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The recommended approach for doing this would be to use the `org.springframework.cache.jcache.JCacheManagerFactoryBean` in which you can inject a `URI`, `Properties` and `ClassLoader`. This factory bean will then use the standard JCache `Caching` class to create the `javax.cache.CacheManager`.

For Ehcache, the `URI` is used to point to an `ehcache.xml` that will then configure the `CacheManager`.

So expanding on your sample config:

```
<bean id="jCacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.jcache.JCacheManagerFactoryBean">
  <property name="cacheManagerUri" value="file://path/to/ehcache.xml"/>
</bean>
<bean id="myCacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.jcache.JCacheCacheManager">
  <property name="cacheManager" ref="jCacheManager" />
</bean>
```

For more information on Ehcache 3 / JCache integration, see [the documentation](http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/3.2/107.html).

Comment: Your answer worked for me, but why do we have to define two cache managers? Can you please offer more details regarding spring caching, JCache configuration, using ehcache as an implementation to JCache? The official documentation of all those three really didn't help much.

Answer (score 2):

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class CacheConfig {

  @Bean
  public JCacheCacheManager jCacheCacheManager() throws IOException {
    return new JCacheCacheManager(cacheManager());
  }

  @Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
  public javax.cache.CacheManager cacheManager() throws IOException {
    XmlConfiguration xmlConfig = new XmlConfiguration(new ClassPathResource("ehcache.xml").getURL());
    EhcacheCachingProvider provider = (EhcacheCachingProvider) Caching.getCachingProvider();
    return provider.getCacheManager(provider.getDefaultURI(), xmlConfig);

  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class CacheConfig {

    @Bean
    public JCacheCacheManager jCacheCacheManager(JCacheManagerFactoryBean jCacheManagerFactoryBean){
        JCacheCacheManager jCacheCacheManager = new JCacheCacheManager();
        jCacheCacheManager.setCacheManager(jCacheManagerFactoryBean.getObject());
        return jCacheCacheManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public JCacheManagerFactoryBean jCacheManagerFactoryBean() throws URISyntaxException {
        JCacheManagerFactoryBean jCacheManagerFactoryBean = new JCacheManagerFactoryBean();
        jCacheManagerFactoryBean.setCacheManagerUri(getClass().getResource("/ehcache.xml").toURI());
        return jCacheManagerFactoryBean;
    }
}
```